# Difference between "свистать" and "свистеть"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Have tried to find out (checked several sources) what the difference is between: "свистать" and "свистеть"?

Do you have an explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the modern language, *свистать* is a little bit outdated, but otherwise is a synonym to *свистеть* ("to whistle").

Historically, it's an iterative, similar to *летать / лететь, плавать / плыть* etc.

In some idioms (*свистать всех наверх!, ищи-свищи!*) or metaphorical meanings "to hiss, to boo (as when expressing discontent)", "to make whistling sound (of a wind)", etc., only one verb of the pair can be used:

> - Играют волны, ветер свищет
> - Профессора на рысаках не ездят, меня освистали бы студенты.